# get the content of one column of each row in the table and then loop on each content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table structure like this (refer below)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>address</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr rowid="1">
            <td class="columnid">1</td><td class="columnname">name 1</td><td class="columnaddress">address 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowid="2">
            <td class="columnid">2</td><td class="columnname">name 2</td><td class="columnaddress">address 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr rowid="3">
            <td class="columnid">3</td><td class="columnname">name 3</td><td class="columnaddress">address 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to get the content from each table row that has attr('columnid') and loop each of it. So the code structure would look like this (refer below)

```
//We have 3 row, get all present rowid (1,2,3)
//count all the row that has rowid attribute
var rowcount = attr('rowid').length();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) //I dont know how to make it but assume in this for statement, I have stored the content from each rowid attribute {
   //alert each rowid here
}
```

how to make it? any help, suggestions, recommendations, ideas, clues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tr[rowid]` which will find all `tr` elements with `rowid` attribute, then use .has() to filter out `tr`s which do not have `td` with class `columnid` like

```
$('tr[rowid]').has('td.columnid').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('rowid'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ouxn30Lm/)

Comment: cool. thank you for the answer, how about getting the content of the rest of the table data like I want to get also the columnname and columnaddress within each row and alert it?

Answer (score 0):

This code will scan all the `td`'s with class `columnid`and alert the `rowid` of the `row` containing it. I hope this is what you want you code to do.

```
$("tr td.columnid").each(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr("rowid"));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/dtxgnbta/1)

Comment: cool. thank you for the answer, how about getting the content of the rest of the table data like I want to get also the columnname and columnaddress within each row and alert it?